# How to create multiple checkbox in canvas

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I get trouble when I try to create a check box in canvas.

My checkbox works well but I don't know how to store value of each item, that mean when user check row 1 , and then they move to another row check box still check row 1, and when user check row 1 and 2 and move to another row, check box will check row 1 and 2.

But I can't find out solution for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify your code to use `selectTodelete` as boolean array instead of int, about like shown below

```
    // ...initialization of DataList
    boolean[] selectTodelete = new boolean[2]; // instead of int
    { selectTodelete[0] = selectTodelete[1] = false; } // init array
    Command editCommand, backCommand,selectCmd, unselectCmd,selectAll;
    //...

    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        //...
        for(int i =0 ; i<countRow; i++ ){
            //draw background
            //...
                     if(selectTodelete[i]){ // was selectTodelete == 1
                            //draw select dot at location for row 'i'
                            //...
                     }
            // remove: you don't need that anymore: if(selectTodelete == 2) {
                            //draw select dot...
            //}

            // draw a checkbox before each item
            // ...
        }
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
        //...
        if(c == selectCmd){
            selectTodelete[selectedItem] = true;
        }
        if(c== unselectCmd){
            selectTodelete[selectedItem] = false;
        }
        if(c == selectAll){
            selectTodelete[0] = selectTodelete[1] = true;
        }
        repaint();
    }
    //...
}
```

## update - answer to question in comments

> I want to get RCID fit to checked it mean when row was checked I can get this id and when I use delete command it will delete all rows were checked

For that, you can expose `selectTodelete` for use outside of its class with getter, or, better yet, with method like below...

```
    boolean isSelected(int elementNum) {
        return elementNum >= 0 && elementNum < selectTodelete.length
                && selectTodelete[elementNum];
    } // modelled after javax.microedition.lcdui.Choice.isSelected
```

...information exposed like that can be further used anywhere when you need it to deal with RCID, like eg in method below:

```
    Vector useSelection(DataList dataList, DataStore[][] ds) {
        Vector result = new Vector();
        int count = ds.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
            if (!dataList.isSelected(i)) {
                continue; // skip non selected
            }
            System.out.println("RCID selected: [" + ds[i][5].cellText + "]");
            result.addElement(ds[i][5]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: sorry brother, can i ask you one more question. in my code i want to get RCID fit to checked it mean when row was checked i can get this id  and when i use delete command it will delete all rows were checked. Thank You

Comment: @MYE I updated the answer to show how to use `selectTodelete` to deal with RCID

Comment: Thank you very much, but im wondering, how to add it into array, because i need to get id to delete item

Comment: im wondering about how to convert Vector in J2Me to int array because i need to get int value to delete record in resultset. In j2me it can be vector().toArray but in J2me how to do this?

Comment: @MYE if you need int value, no need to convert. To get that value at index `i`, just use vector elementAt method: `((Integer)(vector.elementAt(i))).intValue()`